# Strange behavior of `mutate` when applied to a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to `mutate` a `character` column in a dataframe, the result should return another `character` column, but in reality some of the elements in the column are converted to `numeric`. How could this happen?

This is the dataframe, both `sumspec` and `rate.express` are `character` vectors

```
sumspec= c("TA","TCO2")
rate.express = c("(rNC-rPC)*RO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + (rNC-rPC+4/3)*RNO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + (rNC-rPC)*RNO3POC[i]*dstopw[i] + (rNC-rPC+4)*RMnO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + (rNC-rPC+8)*RFeOOHPOC[i]*dstopw[i] + (rNC-rPC+1)*RSO4POC[i]*dstopw[i] + (rNC-rPC)*RCH4POC[i]*dstopw[i] + -2*RO2NH4[i] + -2*RO2Mn[i] + -1*RO2Mn_ads[i] + -2*RO2Fe[i] + -1*RO2Fe_ads[i] + -2*RO2H2S[i] + -2*RO2FeS[i]*dstopw[i] + -8/5*RNO3Mn[i] + -1.8*RNO3Fe[i] + 2*RSO4CH4[i] + -1*RMnO2Fe[i]*dstopw[i] + 2*RMnO2H2S[i]*dstopw[i] + 4*RFeOOHH2S[i]*dstopw[i] + -2*RFeS_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 2*RFeS_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + 2*RCaCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -2*RCaCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 2*RMnCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -2*RMnCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 2*RFeCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -2*RFeCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 10*RAnnite_dis[i]",
"1*RO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RNO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RNO3POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RMnO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RFeOOHPOC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RSO4POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 0.5*RCH4POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RO2CH4[i] + 1*RSO4CH4[i] + 1*RCaCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -1*RCaCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RMnCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -1*RMnCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RFeCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -1*RFeCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i]")
```

Now mutate the colume `rate.express`

```
dH <- data.frame(sumspec,
                 rate.express) %>%
  mutate(RHS = ifelse(
    sumspec == "TA", rate.express,
    paste0("-1.0*(",rate.express,")*dTA/d",sumspec,"[i]")
  ))
```

Which returns

```
> dH$RHS
[1] "1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[2] "-1.0*(1*RO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RNO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RNO3POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RMnO2POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RFeOOHPOC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RSO4POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 0.5*RCH4POC[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RO2CH4[i] + 1*RSO4CH4[i] + 1*RCaCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -1*RCaCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RMnCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -1*RMnCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i] + 1*RFeCO3_dis[i]*dstopw[i] + -1*RFeCO3_pre[i]*dstopw[i])*dTA/dTCO2[i]"
```

So the mutate `rate.express` should just return the original value for the first element but it is converted to numeric. The second element is OK. I think it is converted to `numeric` because

```
> as.numeric(dH$rate.express[1])
[1] 1
```

In stead, if I explicitly use `as.character` to `rate.express`

```
> dH <- data.frame(sumspec,
+                  rate.express) %>%
+     mutate(RHS = ifelse(
+         sumspec == "TA", as.character(rate.express), # explicitly state type
+         paste0("-1.0*(",rate.express,")*dTA/d",sumspec,"[i]")
+     ))
```

Then the result is correct

```
Why did this type conversion happen?
```

Comment: You have a `factor` column, Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` or convert to `character` with `as.character` i.e. `data.frame(sumspec,
                  rate.express, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%  mutate(RHS = ifelse(
     sumspec == "TA", rate.express,
     paste0("-1.0*(",rate.express,")*dTA/d",sumspec,"[i]")
   ))`

Comment: I always thought `factor` is just a subtype of `character` and have never seen this problem before.

Comment: The issue is that `data.frame()` and other functions like `read.csv()` have `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` as the default, which can cause these issues to pop up. Newer packages like `readr` and `tibble` leave them as character, which I think is a more sensible default.

Comment: According to `?factor` `factor returns an object of class "factor" which has a set of integer codes the length of x with a "levels" attribute of mode character and unique`  What you see by conversion is coersion to integer storage mode

Comment: `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` does solve the problem. Thanks! First time come across this issue.

Comment: I'll bear in mind this difference. Thanks.